# stack around a variable per/temp

Tags: c, text-files

When i run the following code, it get stucked around the variable per and I don't understand why.
The Function recives a database(a closed txt file), patient and a pointer to size.

About the Function:
The function returns an array of person containing all the details of potential donors with at least 'min_match' number of identical genes as the patient.

In case there is no full match between a donor and a patient, a transplant can be done with a partial match. By setting min_match to 3, the array will contain all the potential donors with 3 or more matching genes as the patient. A matching gene is a gene with exactly the same sequence as the same gene of the patient.
The array is sorted as follows; 1st criteria: by number of matched genes.
2nd criteria: in case the number of matched genes between two potential donors is identical, the precedence is given to the donor with the least mismatches per gene (difference in DNA sequence on the same location of the gene).
3rd criteria: in case two donors have exactly the same genetic profile, the precedence is given by alphabetical order to the one appearing earlier in the phone book.

The Structure and the function are defined as following:

```
typedef struct person_{
    char name[31];
    char id[10];
    char genes[5][22];
} person;

person* getPotentialDonors(char* database, person patient, int min_match,int *size){
    FILE *db;
    person * matches,per,temp;
    int count,i,j=0,count_per=0,index,big=0,k,countS,countJ,MismatchS,MissmatchJ, minMissS, minMissJ,ind;

    db=fopen(database,"r");
    if(!db) exit(1);

    while(fscanf(db,"%30[^$] %9[^$] %21[^$] %21[^$] %21[^$] %21[^$] %21[^$]%*c",per.name,per.id,per.genes[0],per.genes[1],per.genes[2],per.genes[3],per.genes[4])==7)
    {
        count=0;
        for(i=0;i<5;i++)
            if(!strcmp(patient.genes[i],per.genes[0])||!strcmp(patient.genes[i],per.genes[1])||!strcmp(patient.genes[i],per.genes[2])||!strcmp(patient.genes[i],per.genes[3])||!strcmp(patient.genes[i],per.genes[4])) count++;

        if(count>=min_match) count_per++;
    }


    matches=(person*)malloc(sizeof(person)*count_per);

    rewind(db);

    while(fscanf(db,"%30[^$] %9[^$] %21[^$] %21[^$] %21[^$] %21[^$] %21[^$]%*c",per.name,per.id,per.genes[0],per.genes[1],per.genes[2],per.genes[3],per.genes[4])==7)
    {
        count=0;
        for(i=0;i<5;i++)
            if(!strcmp(patient.genes[i],per.genes[i])) count++;

        if(count>=min_match) 
        {
            strcpy(matches[j].name,per.name);
            strcpy(matches[j].id,per.id);
            strcpy(matches[j].genes[0],per.genes[0]);
            strcpy(matches[j].genes[1],per.genes[1]);
            strcpy(matches[j].genes[2],per.genes[2]);
            strcpy(matches[j].genes[3],per.genes[3]);
            strcpy(matches[j].genes[4],per.genes[4]);
            j++;
        }
    }

    for(index=0;index<count_per;index++){
        big = index;
        for(j=index+1;j<count_per;j++){
            MismatchS = 0;
            MissmatchJ = 0;
            minMissJ =minMissS =21;
            countS=countJ=0;
            for(k=0;k<5;k++){
                MismatchS = 0;
                if(!strcmp(matches[big].genes[k],patient.genes[k])) countS++;
                else
                {
                    for(i=0;i<22;i++){
                        if(matches[big].genes[k][i]!=patient.genes[k][i]) MismatchS++;
                    }
                    if(MismatchS<minMissS) minMissS=MismatchS; 
                }
                if(!strcmp(matches[j].genes[k],patient.genes[k])) countJ++;
                else
                {
                    for(i=0;i<22;i++){
                        if(matches[j].genes[k][i]!=patient.genes[k][i]) MissmatchJ++;
                    }
                    if(MissmatchJ<minMissJ) minMissJ=MissmatchJ; 
                }
            }
            if(countS < countJ)
                big = j;
            else if (countS == countJ &&  minMissJ<minMissS) big=j;
            else if (countS == countJ &&  minMissJ==minMissS && strcmp(matches[j].name,matches[big].name)<0)    big=j;
        }

        strcpy(temp.name,matches[index].name);//Index->temp
        strcpy(temp.id,matches[index].id);
        for(ind=0;ind<5;ind++)
            strcpy( temp.genes[ind],matches[index].genes[ind]);


        strcpy(matches[index].name,matches[big].name);//big->index
        strcpy(matches[index].id,matches[big].id);
        for(ind=0;ind<5;ind++)
            strcpy( matches[index].genes[ind],matches[big].genes[ind]);


        strcpy(matches[big].name,temp.name);//temp->big
        strcpy(matches[big].id,temp.id);
        for(ind=0;ind<5;ind++)
            strcpy(matches[big].genes[ind],temp.genes[ind]);
    }

    fclose(db);
    *size = count_per;

    return matches;
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by "stuck"?

Comment: When I try to run the code, In VS2010, when min_match=1,I recive the messenge run-time check failure #2 - stack around the variable 'per' was corrupted.

Comment: It is a nice runtime check, it tells you that your code overflowed a stack buffer.  Lots of potential for that with hard-coded string lengths and no checking at all that the data in the file actually fits the string buffer.

Comment: @user2600366 Did you find it? I'm so curious, the only thing I can see in this code is using `strncmp` for `strcmp` and `strncpy` for `strcpy`, but it seems `fscanf` adds the 'null' character, although I didn't find it clearly specified.

Comment: Nope I didn't find the problem yet. The file which It's reading from is  vaild. When  min_match is 2 or above, the program doesn't stack.

Answer (score 0):

maybe not the answer to the problem, but my symmetric detector is confused by

```
for(i=0;i<5;i++)
if(!strcmp(patient.genes[i],per.genes[0]) ||!strcmp(patient.genes[i],per.genes[1])||!strcmp(patient.genes[i],per.genes[2]) ||!strcmp(patient.genes[i],per.genes[3])||!strcmp(patient.genes[i],per.genes[4])) count++;
//do something with count
```

and

```
for(i=0;i<5;i++)
    if(!strcmp(patient.genes[i],per.genes[i])) count++;
// do something with count that is supposed to be the same as above
```

Comment: The first for loop updates the counter which decleared in order to calc the array size.the second one was made in order to check whether each line is matched to the array or not.